# Clipping/Splitting line layer based on another layer line running in parallel/alongside it using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I know how to Clip layers files based on another layers using the processing toolbox but how do I clip/split a line layer based on another line that is following parallel/alongside it?

Look at the picture below, the Blue line is separate layer following along the green on in certain points, I want to "split" this blue line layer where it follows with the green one.

**So that only the sections where the green layer line does not go remain (highlighted in Yellow).**

[image]

It is a process that I want to automate into a model.

I am using QGIS 3.4.5.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Flat ended buffers** along with **Difference** to remove the unwanted areas of line, leaving the areas desired.

- **Buffer** Green line (adjust buffer distance as required)
  End cap style: Flat
  Join Style: Miter
- **Difference**
  Input: Blue line
  Overlay Layer: Buffer output

[image: Buffer_Difference]